# Question about synths

Tags: synthesizer, daw, vst

How do people create these really cool synths? No matter how much I play around with the ohmforce VST plugins I installed for reaper I cannot mimic the sound of the synths these people use. Here is an example of what I mean.

How did Xtrullor get such a nice synth in this song? I'd love to get some help on this!

Comment: Note that a lot of the sounds on that track seem to be samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating cool synths is all a question of :

1. Expressivity (modulation)
2. Clarity (mixing)
3. Context (other sounds in track, lead synth?)

The advice I could give you is to stop touching your synth when it is close to what you have in mind.

Depends on the genre but you may also have some expressive synths without being "powerful" (dB speaking);

Sound mixing, effects is really useful but for a start you should prefer creating clean and powerful sounds without any effects (just to train).
FM modulation is a good training.

You could also compare your synths to other synths in banks or even on tracks.

Mid range frequencies usually make the difference (expressivity).

Hope this was helpful,

Cheers,